# getting wrong index when trying to get index of view from subviews array

Tags: ios, swift

swift 2.3
ios 9
xcode 7.3

i have **myView** it's subclass of UIView,

i have a protocol **myViewObject** which have a delegate property of type
**myVieDelgateProtocol**

when object/class conform to the **myViewObject**  protocol,
any time the object moves,it's send's
it's origin and final point to the **myView** via the delegate.

in my app:
i have 3 object's (UIView subclases that conform to the myViewObject protocol ) 
and they are subviews of **myView**,

when they are moving by dragging them, i check the index of the object that moved, i have checked 3 different objects, and the log says same index for all objects, (that can't be true),

whay can't i get the correct index for the objects?

**code:**

```
import UIKit

//a protocol to make shure the conforming object/(DViewObject) is inherting from UIView
public protocol UIViewType:class {
    var  view: UIView {get}
    var  isInsideMyView:Bool {get}
}

extension UIView:UIViewType{
    public var view: UIView {return self}
    public var isInsideMyView:Bool {return self.superview is myView}
}

///a protocol for your object to conform
public protocol  myViewObject:UIViewType{
    var  delegate:myVieDelgateProtocol? {get set}
}

//DelgateProtocol
public protocol myVieDelgateProtocol {

    ///Use this method to send the Object's position from your gesture handler or from the touches methods from your object's class to the delegate
    func object(object: myViewObject , didMovedFromPoint originPoint:CGPoint, toPoint point:CGPoint)
}

extension myView:myVieDelgateProtocol{

    func object(object: myViewObject , didMovedFromPoint originPoint:CGPoint, toPoint point:CGPoint){


        let objectIndex = subviews.indexOf(object.view)
            print("object At Index \(objectIndex!) moved to position: \(object.view.center)\n")

    }
}


 class myView: UIView{}
```

The log:
3 different objects same index:

> object At Index 2 moved to position: (198.5, 58.8333282470703)
>
> object At Index 2 moved to position: (117.83332824707,
>   52.8333435058594)
>
> object At Index 2 moved to position: (37.5, 50.8333282470703)

Comment: indexOf uses the equals and hash methods, you need to determine what "equals" for your view is. Can you print the list of subviews ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the line of code that was causing the issue:
in the moving object's class i was asking:

// self is myViewObject

```
self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)
```

so it wan't be covered/hidden by other subviews while moving,
doing so also changed the order of subview,
if i have 3 object and i'm bringing one to the front, it will gain the index 2
and that is how it suppose to be.